# running python file from excel

Tags: python, vba

I am attempting to run a simple test python script from excel. When I execute from excel, a windows explorer window pops up, but the script is never run. Beginner programmer here. Could really use some help. ideas?

```
Sub RunPython()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\...Programs\Python 3.10"""
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\...test2"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript


End Sub
```

Comment: For start you miss a space when concatenate `PythonExe` and `PythonScript`

Comment: to be more clear, the window that pops up is the file location of Python 3.10.exe

Comment: thank you @buran for the reply. I added the space, but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: if I add file extension to PythonExe and PythonScript, I get "Method 'Run' of object 'IWishSHell3' failed error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are opening a folder not an exe file. `"""C:\Users\...Programs\Python 3.10\python.exe"""

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate Python scripts in OS or shell commands via other language layers like VBA or run scripts at command line, you need to explicitly call the interpreter (i.e., python.exe). Additionally, since quotes can get messy in VBA especially with spaces and special characters in file and path names, consider building the needed shell command via an array of arguments.

Also, as best practice, enclose routine in proper error handling to catch and report runtime errors. Below `args` can be extended if you need to pass arguments into the Python script.

```vb
Sub Run_Py_Script()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
    Dim shell As Object
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 0
    Dim errorCode As Integer

    Dim args(0 To 1) As String
    Dim pyCommand As String
    Dim i As Integer

    args(0) = "C:\Path\To\Python\Install\Folder\python.exe"
    'args(0) = "python"                     ' IF PYTHON INSTALL FOLDER IS IN PATH ENV VARIABLE
    args(1) = "C:\Path\To\Python\myscript.py"

    pyCommand = args(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(args)
        pyCommand = pyCommand & " """ & args(i) & """"
    Next i        
    Debug.Print pyCommand                   ' TEST COMMAND LINE CALL IN CMD OR POWERSHELL

    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    errorCode = shell.Run(pyCommand, style, waitTillComplete)

ExitHandle:
    Set shell = Nothing                     ' RELEASE ALL set OBJECTS
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```